# pusher unbind not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pusher

i am using javascript pusher library (angularjs) with PHP backend.

js:

```
// Enable pusher logging - don't include this in production
Pusher.logToConsole = true;

var pusher = new Pusher('API_KEY', {
        cluster: 'ap2',
        encrypted: true
});
var channel = pusher.subscribe('my-channel');
channel.bind('my-event', function (data) {
   common.flashMsg('success', data.message);
});
```

for bind and unbind code:

```
$scope.workerStatus = function (status) {
        if (status == 'available') {
            common.flashMsg('success', "Welcome Again...!");
            channel.bind('my-event', function (data) {
                common.flashMsg('success', data.message);
            });
        } else {
            common.flashMsg("error", "You're now offline. Good Bye.");
            channel.unbind('my-event', function () {
                common.flashMsg('success', data.message);
            });
        }
}
```

i want to unbind the `channel`,when user is logout and stop notification, but channel `unbind` event not working, user still able to receive notification.
what i am missing?

Comment: i was passing in a reference to a different function so the call was failing, now problem solved with same function in second parameter in `unbind`

Answer (score -1):

I think the reason that you're having an issue is that you're passing in a function to the `unbind` call. Try omitting the second argument in order to remove all listeners for that event. Passing in an event handler is reserved to unbind that specific handler, if you have more than one. This is useful if you're binding multiple event handlers to the event and only want to unbind one of them.

See more here: https://github.com/pusher/pusher-js#bind-and-unbind